# How to Get Most Item list from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

i have two tables: **invoice** and **orderlist**

**Invoice** contains

```
   +----------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
   | orderInvoice   | orderCustomer | orderTime   | orderTotal |
   +----------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
   | 00001          | Nick          | 2012-11-29  | 30.00      |
   | 00002          | Andrew        | 2012-11-29  | 15.00      |
   | 00003          | West          | 2012-11-29  | 80.00      |
   +----------------+---------------+-------------+------------+
```

**orderlist** contains

```
   +----------------+------------------+------+--------+
   | orderInvoice   |   item  |  size  | Qty  | price  |
   +----------------+------------------+------+--------+
   | 00001          |   Coke  |   Can  | 20   | 0.50   |
   | 00001          |   Coke  | Bottle | 10   | 2.00   |
   | 00002          |  Sprite |   Can  | 30   | 0.50   |
   | 00003          |   Coke  | Bottle | 40   | 2.00   |
   +----------------+------------------+------+--------+
```

i want to output like this:

```
   +---------------------------------------------------+
   | Most Popular Soda                                 |
   +---------------------------------------------------+
   | Coke Bottle         50                            |
   | Sprite Can          30                            |
   | Coke Can            20                            |
   +---------------------------------------------------+
   | 2012-11-29                                        |
   +---------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to query it with concat() as ITEM and then count(ITEM) . it looks like i can use them together in a single query.

------------UPDATE----------------

Thank you guys for post the answers. I figured it out the answer(can't do it without your guys help). I will leave the answer there in case others might looking for it as well

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    orderlist.item,
    orderlist.size
) AS item,
orderlist.orderInvoice,
SUM(orderlist.Qty) AS Qty
FROM
    orderlist
INNER JOIN invoice ON nvoice.orderInvoice = orderlist.orderInvoice
WHERE
    Invoice.orderTime = '2012-11-29'
GROUP BY
    item
ORDER BY
    Qty DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

`select item,sum(qty) as quantity from orderlist group by item;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select item, size, SUM(qty) quantity
from 
orderlist
group by item, size

order by quantity desc
```